# Determing whether an area is Inland or Coastal

Tags: climate, temperature, wind, coastal

I have determined an area to be along the coastline just from looking at its climagraph. Its temperatures only range from -10 to 21 so there is not a large range of temperatures because it is being moderated by the ocean. However now I need to see if the wind speeds provided back my answer up. The windspeeds range from 10.7 km/hr to 15km/hr and there is only 8 days a year where the windspeeds are greater or equal to 52km/hr. So I was not given the name of this location but just from this information about windspeeds I need to back up my answer saying that this region is a coastline region. But how do I go about that?

Comment: Do you have any information on what exactly the values represent?  Are -10 and 21 the daily averages, or is that the gap between lows in the winter and highs in the summer?  And 52 km/hr, is that max gusts, max sustained, or daily averages?  Helps understand how large the ranges really are.

Answer (score 2):

Well, let's start with a rough global map (from NCEP Reanalysis) of the average winds speeds (in meters per second):
[image: NCEP Reanalysis 1981-2010, see http://www.esrl.noaa.gov/psd/cgi-bin/data/composites/printpage.pl for making your own]

Multiply by 3.6 to get km/hr.  So your range is basically from 3 m/s to 4 m/s.  So you're looking at the medium blue color basically.
There are some coastal locations.  But generally, coastal locations will have quite a bit of wind...

[image: Wind friction effects, courtesy Environment Canada]

What this graphic says is that basically winds at the ocean are 15-60% increased from typical land values.  Even more upsetting to being coastal is the 8 days less than 52 km/hr that you mention.  You're in a location reasonably mid-latitude, so you've traditionally got the big wind storms that often affect the coastal areas, such as Nor'Easters, and Bering Sea cyclones.  I'd think it'd be hard to find an oceanic city that doesn't get above 52 km/hr more than 8 days during a year outside the tropics (assuming you're talking about short burst of 52 km/hr and not daily averages, but even daily averages I'd think might surpass 52 km/hr 8 days per year in the majority of seaboard cities).

So I'd be surprised to see that it is truly a coastal location.  However there are a couple places with connections to water that might fit still.
 1 - Near inland seas\lakes would have somewhat lower wind because of the diminished water fetch available and the decreased percentage of the year that wind flows over such water.
 2 - The transition zone from marine winds to land winds is probably only something like 10-100 miles, while temperature moderation is still significant, even moreso if there is water on many sides.

Because your temperature range is only indeed 31 C (56 F) wide, that certainly does seem to still suggest it has significant moisture influences.

Now, 21 C seems a fairly cool value (especially if that's the absolute maximum daytime peak during the year, but even an average of 21 seems a tad cool, especially for cities not right on the water.
So that suggests to me that it's pretty far north, or perhaps abuts rather cool waters.

So, looking at the map, and based upon those ideas, I'd think the favorite might be inland Russia or China... or maybe around Italy\Greece.  Just the right city location in the northern US or Canada might work too, like Portland (Oregon), Detroit, or Ottawa.

Comment: so you think I am wrong when I say that it's a coastal region?

Comment: Yeah, I'm hesitant on it being right on the coast myself.  But maybe more like 100 miles inland, or near a large lake?  But have certainly been wrong in my time!

Comment: To summarize, look at the map.  There's very few places on the coast that are medium blue.  And to match the winds you gave, the place should be.

Comment: It wasn't bad thinking though generally, certainly a fair direction to go.  Just the subtleties of the exact values seems to turn it another way.

Comment: reading through your explanation i think you thought that there was only 8 days a year with winds less than 52, however there are only 8 days a year with the winds that exceed 52. So the average annual wind speed is only 12.9, the temperature in have providing is just the daily average for each month

Comment: No, saying that seaside locations should be windier locations, both in terms of average windspeed, and in terms of number of extreme days.

Comment: Seems climate graph websites leave something to be desired generally, but http://goo.gl/w17qM7 offers a useful comparison.  Most sites have average winds well over your 6.6-9.3 range (when converted to mph).  Plus in Fahrenheit the variation you give 55 degrees.  On that graph, even Detroit falls short of the gap.  But it's in the right ballpark, and out of the cities provided, Detroit and Pittsburgh are closest (Portland has good winds, but too small temperature variation).  Hope I've given you some direction in your search!